# How to share terminal command output in realtime via a web page?

Tags: terminal, console, streaming

As programming work often requires us to share our terminal output, I am looking for a persistent way to share the output (stdout and stderr) via a web page.

Old school approach was copy/paste to gist or similar service, even piping would work. Still this does not give you colored console and real time.

Another nice to have feature was to be able to use a cloud storage service to store the uploaded content. Still stuff like AWS S3 is not usable because is has no support for streamed upload and download. Mainly an object becomes available only when you finished uploading it, which means the shared command output could not be accessed before the command is finished.

Identified requirements:

- **persistency**, the uploaded content need to be up for at least 30 days
- **ANSI** coloring support, because plain text is hard to read
- **live output streaming**: the content should be accesible even if the command didn't finish yet
- **opensource client**
- (optional) **opensource server** so you could host your own and not rely on service that could go offline without notice or change its TOS.

I did some research before and here are my current findings:

- [seashells](https://seashells.io/) is working but has some serious problems only last 5 executions are kept and all are recycled after 24 hours. The second one is that the server is not open-source and the entire project has one studend behind with no plans to open-source it. This makes it hi
- [streamhut](https://github.com/miguelmota/streamhut) - 4y old abandonware?
- [rtail](http://rtail.org/) - 4y old abandonware

Notable but not usable:

- [tmate](https://tmate.io/) sharing terminal sessions not command output
- [gotty](https://github.com/yudai/gotty) same as above

Do you know another approach that would work?

Comment: Almost 5 years by now. Do you have a solution yet? I'm interested in the exact same thing. I developed a console application in C# that output to the command line console. I'm interested in creating a web interface for customers to run the application and be able to see the output inside a web browser real time.